# In a git reflog, HEAD@{0} is called what exactly?

Tags: git

If I reflog my master branch on a simple repository. It might look something like this:

```
33e8ab2 master@{0}: commit: 3rd commit
e054213 master@{1}: commit: 2nd commit
d57537e master@{2}: commit: 1st commit
bbc0c23 master@{3}: commit: initial commit
```

What exactly do you call `master@{n}`?

My initial though was that it was a reference. But references point to a specific commit. Is it a relative reference, that is, relative to the number of actions on the tip of the branch?

My questions:

What is the most semantic term for things like: `master@{n}`, `HEAD@{n}`, `master@{1.day.ago}`?

Are all three of the above the same types of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of [gitrevisions](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions). Specifically, `<ref>@{n}` [specifies the n-th prior value of that ref](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltrefnamegtltngtemegemmaster1em).

Answer (score 2):

The meanings from `git reflog --help`

> Reflogs are useful in various Git commands, to specify the old value
>   of a   reference.

**For example:**

```
  HEAD@{2} means "where HEAD used to be two moves ago", 

  master@{one.week.ago} means "where master used to point to one
  week ago in this local repository",
```